# How to install an old version of the Direct X Api in GitHub actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm working on an implementation of continuous integration in [this project](https://github.com/yiays/pcsx2), which requires an old version of the [DirectX SDK from June 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812). Is it possible to install this as a part of a GitHub Actions workflow at all? It may build with any version of the SDK as long as it's compatible with Windows 7.

[Here](https://github.com/yiays/pcsx2/blob/master/.github/workflows/buildbot.yml)'s the workflow I've written so far, and [here](https://wiki.pcsx2.net/PCSX2_Documentation/Compiling_on_Windows)'s the general building for Windows guide I'm following...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a working setup for project using DX2010, however i am not running installer (which always failed for me during beta, maybe it's fixed nowadays) but extracting only parts required for build. Looking at link you provided, this is exactly what guide recommends :)

First, `DXSDK_DIR` variable is set using [::set-env](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) "command". Variable most likely should point to directory outside default location, which can be overwritten if repository is checked out *after* preparing DX files.

```yaml
- name:  Config
  run:   echo ::set-env name=DXSDK_DIR::$HOME/cache/
  shell: bash
```

I didn't want to include DX files in repository, so they had to be downloaded when workflow is running. To avoid doing that over and over again [cache](https://github.com/actions/cache/) action is used to keep files between builds.

```yaml
- name: Cache
  id:   cache
  uses: actions/cache@v1
  with:
   path: ~/cache
   key:  cache
```

And finally, downloading and extracting DX2010. This step will run only if cache wasn't created previously or current workflow cannot create/restore caches (like `on: schedule` or `on: repository_dispatch`).

```yaml
- name:  Cache create
  if:    steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
  run:   |
         curl -L https://download.microsoft.com/download/a/e/7/ae743f1f-632b-4809-87a9-aa1bb3458e31/DXSDK_Jun10.exe -o _DX2010_.exe
         7z x _DX2010_.exe DXSDK/Include -o_DX2010_
         7z x _DX2010_.exe DXSDK/Lib/x86 -o_DX2010_
         mv _DX2010_/DXSDK $HOME/cache
         rm -fR _DX*_ _DX*_.exe
  shell: bash
```

Aaand that's it, project is ready for compilation.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you. I assume it'll be the right answer for anyone searching for this question so I'll mark it as correct. But it isn't working in this environment, despite setting the environment varaible, it a submodule in this project is still using the DXAPI built into Windows 10.

Comment: @AsrielRepp Hah, i had similar problem before upstream tweaked their setup. As temporary workaround, i used `sed` to edit `.vcxproj` (tweaking/adding `<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>` and `<AdditionalLibraryDirectories>`). You could also use your own `.vcxproj` and overwrite one in submodule when workflow is running. Yea, that's dirty, and adds extra maintenance, but could be a way to go if PR is not an option.

Comment: I found the vcxproj file that calls the environment variable; https://github.com/yiays/pcsx2/blob/master/plugins/spu2-x/src/Windows/Spu2-X.vcxproj#L118
It's already calling the environment variable correctly, any idea why it would still end up using the XAudio plugin at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\xaudio2.h`?

Comment: @AsrielRepp Probably due to fact it's set for `SndOut_XAudio2_27.cpp` **only** and at same time `SndOut_XAudio2.cpp` [includes xaudio2.h](https://github.com/yiays/pcsx2/blob/503deebe8f4b112fa516a3213e720884bc2877c0/plugins/spu2-x/src/Windows/SndOut_XAudio2.cpp#L23). Take a look [here](https://github.com/phobos2077/sfall/blob/master/sfall/ddraw.vcxproj) - all paths to `DXSDK_DIR` are set at configuration(s) level, so it's passed to every compiled file; once set that way, you don't even have to remember about it.

Comment: Tried that, no change... I've also tested this on multiple physical Windows 10 machines, and get the same error regardless of any method I use to set the environment variable. I might try opening an issue on the original repo and see what they have to say.

Comment: Figured it out with a little help, I was fetching the repo after downloading and extracting DXSDK in the same directory, so the fetch command was deleting the DXSDK folder.